# What is E[X]? What is Var(X)?

Tags: continuity, expectation, uniform-distribution, poisson-distribution, variance

The number of accidents *X* that a person has in a given year is a Poisson
random variable with mean *Y* . However, Y ∼ *Uniform* ([2, 4]). Calculate:

(a) E[*X*]

(b) Var(*X*)

**Extra**

My understanding of the problem is that E[*X*] = *Y*, where *Y* is our λ. So do we find the CDF of *Y* in order to calculate a and b? I think I'm just overcomplicating the problem.

Comment: Conditional expectations may help: $$\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y] ] = \mathbb{E}[Y] = ?$$
(from the [Law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation). And the [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance) should come in handy too.)

Answer (score 2):

$\operatorname{E}(X\mid Y)=Y$, so by the law of total expectation, $\operatorname{E}(X) = \operatorname{E}(\operatorname{E}(X\mid Y)) = \operatorname{E}(Y) = 3$.

For the Poisson distribution, the variance is the same as the expected value, so $\operatorname{var}(X\mid Y) = Y$.  Then the law of total variance tells us that
$$
\operatorname{var}(X) = \operatorname{E}(\operatorname{var}(X\mid Y)) + \operatorname{var}(\operatorname{E}(X\mid Y)) = \operatorname{E}(Y) + \operatorname{var}(Y) = 3 + \frac 1 3.
$$

Comment: Thank you! I was doing that at first, but it seemed too simple.